# JSONException Error

Tags: android, jsonexception

[image: Here is the stack trace.]

Note that the Asynctask is working perfectly.

What is the problem here? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Can you post the Log here instead of Image

Comment: First of all Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Clearly off topic as Questions seeking debugging help.

Comment: it look like your response string is not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read property from `array`, use below syntax

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray (response.toString());
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
String url = object.getString("image");
```